# Using inputbox to limit attempts in excel VBA numbers game

Tags: vba

I have created a numbers game. I can limit the number of attempts in the code but would prefer to create an inputbox that allows the user to select how many attempts they would like. Tried several ways but without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are lucky. First try, and got two answers you like. Forum rules require that you should mark the one you implemented as "Selected". Please do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first sub, ask the user how many guesses that want with a `InputBox` with a limit on input *(numeric input only via `Type:= 1`)*. The input defaults to 10 although the user can change to desired number of guesses. It's worth noting your guess box could benefit from using the similar syntax (i.e. limit to numeric).

Once you have a input from the user just pass that to your game macro as a variable

```
Sub GuessingGame()

Dim Answer As String
Dim Max_Tries As Long    '<--- New Line

Answer = MsgBox("Would you like to play a game?", vbYesNo, "Secret Number")

If Answer = vbYes Then
    Max_Tries = Application.InputBox("How many tries would you like?", "Attempts", 10, Type:=1)    '<--- New Line
    StartGame Max_Tries    '<--- Updated
Else
    Answer = MsgBox("Have a nice day!", vbExclamation, "Secret Number")
End If


End Sub
```

---

Adjust your actual game macro to include a parameter (See first line) and then just replace your hardcoded limit of 10 with the new parameter variable that is supplied by user.

Another easy fix: You also need to start with `turns = 1`, else you are giving away a free turn. When the loop starts for the first iteration you are on `turn = 1`. Then the loop adds iterates and next time is `turn = 2`. In your current state the first try is `turn 0` and second try is `turn 1` etc.

```
Sub StartGame(Max_Tries As Long)   '<-- Updated

Dim SecretNumber, MsgReturnVal, turns As Integer
Dim Guess, msg As String
Randomize

turns = 1    '<--- Updated

SecretNumber = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)

msg = "Guess the Secret Number"

Do While turns <= Max_Tries    '<--- Updated
    Guess = InputBox("Enter a number [0...100]:", msg)
    turns = turns + 1

    If Guess = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("Game Over, user canceled!")
        End
    End If
 
    If Not IsNumeric(Guess) Then
        MsgBox "You can only enter a number in this field"
        End
    End If

 Select Case CInt(Guess)
    Case Is = SecretNumber
           MsgReturnVal = MsgBox("You guessed the Secret Number " & SecretNumber & "!!" & " In " & turns & " Turns!! ", vbExclamation, "Game Over")
           End
    Case Is < SecretNumber
            msg = "The Secret Number is HIGHER. Guess again!"
    Case Else
            msg = "The Secret Number is LOWER. Guess again!"
    End Select
 
Loop

If turns > Max_Tries Then MsgBox "Sorry too many guesses!!"    '<--- Updated

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works, great! I was struggling with it!

Comment: It isn't true that a free turn is given away if the turn counter doesn't start at 1. The logic is that 0 turns were used before the first. Therefore the counter must be zero at the start. Thereafter it must be incremented in such a way that it shows the number of turns taken and terminated when the maximum number has been reached.

Comment: Leave it how you had it and enter 3 tries. Notice it will give you 4 tries. If you enter 5 tries it will give you 6. And so on

Answer (score -1):

I think I just ab out got it worked out. Please play.

```
Sub GuessingGame()
    ' 144

    Dim Answer      As Variant
    
    Answer = MsgBox("Would you like to play a game?", _
                    vbYesNo Or vbQuestion, "Secret Number")
    
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Do
            ' 3 is the default suggestion
            Answer = InputBox("Great! How many tries would you like?", _
                              "Secret Number", 3)
            If Answer = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Thank you. Please play again another time." & _
                       vbCr & "Good bye.", vbCritical, "Cancelled!"
                Exit Sub                        'stop the game
            ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Answer) Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a number.", vbExclamation, "Wrong entry"
            ElseIf Answer > 100 Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a smaller number.", , "Maximum is 100"
            End If
        Loop Until Answer > 0 And Answer < 100
        StartGame Answer
    Else
        MsgBox "OK. Have a nice day!", vbExclamation, "Secret Number"
    End If
End Sub

Sub StartGame(ByVal Guesses As Integer)
    ' 144

    Dim SecretNumber        As Integer          ' value = 0 here
    Dim MsgReturnVal        As Integer
    Dim Turns               As Integer
    Dim Guess               As Variant
    Dim Msg                 As String
    
    Randomize
    SecretNumber = Int((100 * Rnd) + 1)
    Msg = "Guess the Secret Number"
    
    Do
        Do
            Guess = InputBox("Attempt " & Turns + 1 & " of " & Guesses & "." & _
                             vbCr & "Enter a number [0...100]:", Msg)
            If Guess = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Game Over. Thanks for trying.", _
                       vbCritical, "Cancelled!"
                Exit Sub                        'stop the game
            End If
        
            If IsNumeric(Guess) Then
                Guess = CInt(Guess)             'check CInt function in notes if needed
            Else
                MsgBox "You can only enter a number in this field", _
                       vbInformation, "Invalid entry"
            End If
        Loop While Guess < 0 Or Guess > 100
    
        Select Case Guess
            Case SecretNumber
                MsgBox "Cngratulations! You guessed the Secret Number " & SecretNumber & "!!" & vbCr & _
                       "You took " & Turns + 1 & " Attempts. Well done!!", vbExclamation, _
                       "Game Over"
                Msg = "DONE"
            Case Is < SecretNumber
                Msg = "HIGHER"
             Case Else
                Msg = "LOWER"
         End Select

    If Msg = "DONE" Then
        Turns = Guesses + 1                     ' terminate loop
    Else
        Turns = Turns + 1
        If Turns = Guesses Then
            MsgBox "Sorry! That's wrong, too.", vbInformation, "Game Over"""
        Else
            MsgBox "The Secret Number is " & Msg & " than " & Guess & "." & vbCr & _
                   "You have " & Guesses - Turns & " more guesses.", _
                   vbInformation, "Try again"
        End If
    End If
    Loop While Turns < Guesses                 ' 'Do While (True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this also works great! With counter message! Brilliant!